# Customize Authentication Dropdown in Business Objects 4.1 BI Launch Pad

Tags: authentication, business-objects

Looking for a way to customize the authentication dropdown presented to users when logging into the BI LaunchPad application, version 4.1 (known as InfoView in prior versions).  Currently, users are asked to make one of the following choices: Enterprise, LDAP, Windows AD, SAP, JD Edwards Enterprise, Oracle EBS, PeopleSoft Enterprise, and Siebel7.

[image: Screenshot of Authentication Types in Dropdown]

The `BIlaunchpad.properties` file has already been modified as follows:

```
authentication.visible=true
authentication.default=secEnterprise
```

This was done to allow the users to choose (some are logging in with Windows AD, most with Enterprise) their authentication type.  My goal is to remove the extra options (LDAP, SAP, etc.) so that if a user tries to choose their authentication type, only the two 'valid' options will be visible to them.

Again, I've already set the properties for the default and making the dropdown visible.  I'm not interested in changing those, just in limiting the options within the list.

Is there any way to customize what authentication types appear in this drop down?

Comment: [This post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2004103) has a similar question asked about halfway down by Mark Richardson.

Answer (score -1):

Authentication Types correlate to what was selected at the time of installation.  If you see JD Edwards, Peoplesoft, Oracle EBS, Sievel, etc. then those database types were selected during the time of installation.  You can perform a Modify install to add\remove these options.

If they are already listed in the drop down box, you can remove them form the selection list by going to Authentication > choosing the Authentication Type (ie. Oracle EBS), and Disabling the authenticatoin type.  This should exclude it from the drop down list.

If you see these authentication types listed in the drop down box, but you do NOT see them listed under the Authentication area -- there may have been a hiccup during a patch or installation.  You can resolve by trying to Modify the install, adding the database types, then repeating the Modify, and de-selecting them.

Comment: Disabling the Authentication types don't remove them from login page. All options are per default not enabled but still in the authentication type list.